# Updating multiple columns when inserting a record into MYSQL database via Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to insert values into a few columns in my MYSQL table record via a form on Android Studio. However, my code only updates the first column and the automated id of the table. How do I insert data into all the columns I require?

My MySQL database table (users) is on a hostgator server. I've uploaded the php file (create-new-profile.php) into the file manager of the server. My CreateProfileActivity.java activity contains code to send the data from the edittext form into my hostgator server via the php file.

/create-new-profile.php

```
include 'config.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {

$UserID = $_POST["user_tag"];
$FirstName = $_POST["first_name"];
$LastName = $_POST["last_name"];
$DateOfBirth = $_POST["date_of_birth"];
$SecurityID = $_POST["security_id"];
$Gender = $_POST["gender"];
$Citizen = $_POST["citizen"];


 $InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO users 
(userid,firstname,lastname,dob,securityid,gender,citizen) values ('$UserID','$FirstName','$LastName','$DateOfBirth','$SecurityID','$Gender','$Citizen');";

 if(mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSQL)){

 echo "Your Profile Has Been Updated.";
 }else{
     echo "Error: " . $InsertSQL . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 }else{
 echo "Please Try Again";
 }

?>
```

/Lines 141-280 CreateProfileActivity.java

```
  public void CreateUserProfile(){


        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {



            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CreateProfileActivity.this, "Creating Profile", "Please Wait", false, false);
            }

            @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

                super.onPostExecute(string1);

                 progressDialog.dismiss();

                 Toast.makeText(CreateProfileActivity.this, string1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

            HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

            HashMapParams.put(UserTag, user.getUid());

            HashMapParams.put(FirstName, firstname);

            HashMapParams.put(LastName, lastname);

            HashMapParams.put(DateOfBirth, dateOfBirth);

            HashMapParams.put(SecurityID, securityid);

            HashMapParams.put(Gender, gender);

            HashMapParams.put(Citizen, citizen);



            String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest("http://www.mabs.lk/php/create-new-profile.php", HashMapParams);

            return FinalData;
        }
    }

        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
            AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
    }




public class ImageProcessClass{

    public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);

            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

            bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();

            RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String RC2;

                while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                    stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
            if (check)
                check = false;
            else
                stringBuilder.append("&amp;");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilder.append("=");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

I expect the id (autonumber), userid, firstname, lastname, dob, securityid, gender, citizen columns of my MYSQL 'users' table to be updated. But only the 'id' and 'userid' columns are updated.

Comment: Did you try to print incoming params in php script? I think you should not encode params in url during POST on "Android side"

Comment: First, determine if the backend is even getting the POST variables by echoing them like this: `echo $_POST["first_name"]`. Thus, you'll know whether the problem lies on backend PHP or the android activity code.

Comment: @PrahladYeri the echoing outputs a blank. So, the problem is probably in the android activity.